# PHP Variables, Is it more efficient to use local copys of object vars in class methods

Tags: php, optimization

Say I have this class:

```
class A {
    private
        $var_a,
        $var_b;

    public function do_something(){
        $local_var_a = $this->var_a;

        // ... Lots of use of $local_var_a

        $this->var_a = $local_var_a;
    }

    public function do_something_else(){

        // ... Lots of use of $this->var_a
    }
}
```

Which function is the 'better' one to use and why?

Comment: Yes, working with local vars is fractionally faster than with class vars; but it's never a good idea to micro-optimize until you know you have a problem

Comment: I'd probably just go with `$local_var_a &= $this->var_a` to save on the final reassignment back.

Comment: It really depends on what you are doing and complexity of your function. If you will be using the value later on prior to reassignment to the class variable, then it might be a sound decision to assign it to local variable first.

Comment: It's *really* unlikely that the answer to this question will affect performance in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Better*** is a very ambiguous term. Related to coding in most cases it usually means

- Memory usage - does it eat away your ram?
- Performance - is it fast?
- Usability and Readability - can you (or someone else working on the code) understand whats going on?

The difference in memory usage and performance are very tiny, and I'm no friend of micro-optimization (unless I have too much time at my hands), so I would answer for those two points: it doesn't matter.

For usability and readability I prefer `function do_something_else()`, this makes it way easier for me and someone else to understand how the code works, how it can be tested and documented.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely "public function do_something_else()".

Reason: It is more readable.

There is no need to care about performance on this level.

Comment: With "this level" being the example code that obviously isn't the actual code in use. The question title is about efficiency, not readability.

Comment: @Leigh since code is much more often read than written, the more readable your code is the more efficiently you can work with it. regarding performance the question is about premature micro-optimization and of no interest whatsoever.

Comment: @Gordon: and its executed far more than it is either written or read. The nature of the question may be of no interest to you, but nevertheless the question was asked. For all you know it could simply have been to satisfy the askers curiosity and expand their own knowledge, whether or not it's readable does not help answer the fact of the question.

Comment: @Leigh on the contrary. Gunnar's suggestion is the only reasonable answer to the question because the performance impact of the two approaches is negligible and a micro-optimization (if at all). There is absolutely nothing to worry about performance here. Besides, it is pointless to tell the OP synthetic approach X is faster than Y outside any real environment. If the OP is really interested whether it makes a difference in his application, he should use a Profiler.